# How to put SharePoint 2013 logo above menu?

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, master-pages

Is there a way to move the logo from its default location (to the left of the menu) to above the menu? I can't find any resources on how to do this.

I've tried downloading the existing master page (seattle) and changing it (and checking it in, etc), with some tweaks, but there's no impact, so much so that I had to verify it was actually active.

One change included move this:

```
<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSiteLogo" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" runat="server"   id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" >
        <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=23" runat="server"/>
    </SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
```

from line 354 to various places, such as above lines 216, 217, 218, or 219, or after 326 (above the ribbon sections). No change. I'm admittedly guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer is here, based on Maarten's. This includes hiding the left nav. I had to raise the #siteicon (a container) to 100px high to add some space between the logo and the menu beneath it.

```
<style type="text/css">

#sideNavBox { display: none; }
#contentBox { margin-left: 20px; }
#topNav {  margin-top: 50px; }

#siteIcon { height: 100px; }

.ms-siteicon-img {
max-height: 200px;
max-width: 500px; }

#s4-bodyContainer #titleAreaBox.ms-table, #s4-bodyContainer #titleAreaBox > 
#titleAreaRow {display:block;}

#s4-bodyContainer #titleAreaBox > #titleAreaRow > #siteIcon 
{float:left;display:block;margin:0 auto;}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this via CSS. Don't even necessarily need to edit the master page.

```
#s4-bodyContainer #titleAreaBox.ms-table, #s4-bodyContainer #titleAreaBox > #titleAreaRow {display:block;}
#s4-bodyContainer #titleAreaBox > #titleAreaRow > #siteIcon {float:none;display:block;margin:0 auto}
```

To get any additional formatting you want, additional styling will be needed of course :) But that will center the site icon.

Comment: Hi Maarten. This is good, but I actually wanted it to the left. Also, it's still tiny and I need to make the logo quite a bit bigger. I've been trying to tweak your code to fix both but haven't figured it out. Any other tips?

Comment: If you want it bigger just set height/width of #siteIcon to whatever size you want.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to be right. #siteIcon makes the container around it bigger if I set the height property. Diving into it via Chrome's dev tools, I find this: <img id="ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2" class="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" src="/sites/new_dpcpsi/SiteAssets/My_Logo.png" alt="My Intranet"> but that has no effect (if I target the img id). Any ideas? I can't impact the size of the logo or make it be to the left (it's centered). Thanks

Comment: Okay I got it bigger with this: .ms-siteicon-img { max-height: 200px;
max-width: 500px; } Now I just need to get it to the left instead of centered

Comment: Okay got it by changing your "#siteIcon {float:none}" to float:left, of course. Lost that detail in all my tinkering.